# How do I correctly parse an XMI file using jdom 2?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jdom-2, xmi

I want to parse an XMI file using jdom2, but I can't seem to get information from it. Here's an example:

```
element.getAttributes()  -> [[Attribute: xsi:type="coremodel:Place"],[Attribute: id="p_InitialNode1"], [Attribute: OutArcs="out_InitialNode1"]]
element.getAttributeValue("id") -> p_InitialNode1
element.getAttributeValue("xsi:type") -> null
```

I don't understand why I have null, when I expected `coremodel:Place`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I edited your question for clarity, and made the title a bit more descriptive so that those that can answer it are more likely to notice it. I also consolidated your tags a bit. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it's just by declaring a new namespace for xsi

```
 Namespace namespace = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

and it works